# How can I reinitialize the readline module in Python?

Tags: python, signals, readline

In my python program I need to catch the WINCH signal like this:

```
def WinResize(num, stack):
    # DO SOME STUFF HERE

signal.signal(signal.SIGWINCH, WinResize)
```

The problem is that readline doesn't get the signal and its internal view of the window is false. I tried a trick using

```
readline.set_completer(readline.get_completer())
```

at the end of the WinResize function which partially solves my problem but not completely. With this solution, the new size is updated on readline if i continue to give input until it goes to newline. Until that point it has internally the previous size.

If I don't catch the signal, readline works as expected. I want to completely solve this issue.

Here is a video that demonstrates the issue:
https://streamable.com/1tja9g

Comment: please include a minimal example that shows the issue.  I have no idea how your trick relates to the issue.

Comment: @LhasaDad I edited the question and uploaded a video. It shows first the bug and secondly what is the expected behavior when removing the signal handler.

Comment: Thanks for trying but the appropriate thing to do is to update the code in the example.  providing links out to images or videos is frowned up and will likely not end up with any responses.

Comment: is the readline trick being run within the winresize function?

Comment: the real question is: why not readline can't catch the signal properly when i try to handle it?

Comment: I believe video is the best way to show the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after countless experiments I found the solution to my problem. When I import the readline module AFTER setting up my WINCH signal handler it works as expected. I don't know why though.